# What does the squiggle (tilde) i.e. `~` operator do in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The tilde operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python)

What does the squiggle i.e. `~` operator do in Python?

(This is probably Python 101 for most, but I came across `~` in code and had no idea what it was, and it took me a surprising amount of research to figure it out, so hopefully this Q&A can help someone down the road.)

Comment: In general, the place to look for this sort of thing is directly in the language reference.

Comment: It "flips the bits" of an integral value.  The same operator exists in C, C++, Java, etc.

Comment: Indeed, that's the first thing I did. I searched for ~ in the python docs. Which came up with nothing. I think the squiggle character messes with searches.

Comment: But then, why do you think it will be found on SO with that title? ;)

Comment: this symbol is called [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde), next time it will be easier to search for `tilde operator python` in your favorite search engine

Comment: To help figure out what to google for punctuation, you can type things like `help('~')` at the prompt.  This brings up a table, and searching for `~` reveals it's a "bitwise NOT" operator.  After that, searching is easy.

Comment: Ah yes, it is essentially a duplicate of that. The issue is with discovering the answer. I did look around SO for an answer, but only searched for "squiggle" not "tilde".

Comment: Good point about searching on SO, added "squiggle" to title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the [unary bitwise invert operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations).

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its plain or long integer argument. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`. It only applies to integral numbers.