# What does the ~ operator do in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my attempt at understanding what it does:

```
>>> ~
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print ~
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ~ = cheese
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ~ = "21"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 2 ~ 1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ~ = "w"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = "w"
>>> a
'w'
>>> print ~8
-9
>>> print ~w

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    print ~w
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
>>> print ~"w"
```

It seems to only work with numbers, so an explanation and a link to some documentation would be very helpful.

Comment: [Googlemedo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python)

Comment: I thought it was called a tridle

Comment: I have it on [good authority](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/twiddle.html) that it is pronounced "twiddle". On the [other hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL#Operators) it might be pronounced "select".

Comment: For the love of what you think is good, could you stop it with the down votes? I get it already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`~`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) is a unary operator (i.e. it takes only one argument) which calculates the [**bitwise inverse**](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) of its argument. The result is `-x - 1`, because in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, `-x` is the same as inverting all bits and then adding one.