# Counting the number of non-NaN elements in a numpy ndarray in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, nan

I need to calculate the number of non-NaN elements in a numpy ndarray matrix. How would one efficiently do this in Python? Here is my simple code for achieving this:

```
import numpy as np

def numberOfNonNans(data):
    count = 0
    for i in data:
        if not np.isnan(i):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Is there a built-in function for this in numpy? Efficiency is important because I'm doing Big Data analysis.

Thnx for any help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You mean efficient in terms of memory?

Comment: +1 I was thinking about CPU time, but yeah why not memory as well. The faster and cheaper the better =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi A memory efficient version wil be `sum(not np.isnan(x) for x in a)`, but in terms of speed it is slow compared to @M4rtini numpy version.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thank you very much! I need to see which one is more important in my application =)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

```
np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(data))
```

`~` inverts the boolean matrix returned from `np.isnan`.

`np.count_nonzero` counts values that is not 0\false. `.sum` should give the same result. But maybe more clearly to use `count_nonzero`

Testing speed:

```
In [23]: data = np.random.random((10000,10000))

In [24]: data[[np.random.random_integers(0,10000, 100)],:][:, [np.random.random_integers(0,99, 100)]] = np.nan

In [25]: %timeit data.size - np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data))
1 loops, best of 3: 309 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(data))
1 loops, best of 3: 345 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit data.size - np.isnan(data).sum()
1 loops, best of 3: 339 ms per loop
```

`data.size - np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data))` seems to barely be the fastest here. other data might give different relative speed results.

Comment: Maybe even `numpy.isnan(array).sum()`? I'm not very proficient with numpy though.

Comment: @msvalkon, It will count the number of NaN, while OP want the number of non-NaN elements.

Comment: +1 Thnx guys for your help =) I can check the run-time of these alternatives =)

Comment: @goncalopp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python =)

Comment: @goncalopp the `~` inverts the matrix. I think it's implemented as a `__not__` for ndarrays.

Comment: An extension of @msvalkon answer: `data.size - np.isnan(data).sum()` will be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Ophion added some speed test, the difference was pretty small.

Answer (score 23):

## Quick-to-write alternative

Even though is not the fastest choice, if performance is not an issue you can use:

`sum(~np.isnan(data))`.

### Performance:

```
In [7]: %timeit data.size - np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data))
10 loops, best of 3: 67.5 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit sum(~np.isnan(data))
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit np.sum(~np.isnan(data))
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

To determine if the array is sparse, it may help to get a proportion of nan values

```py
np.isnan(ndarr).sum() / ndarr.size
```

If that proportion exceeds a threshold, then use a sparse array, e.g.
- https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, but a bit slower alternative is to do it over indexing.

```
np.isnan(data)[np.isnan(data) == False].size

In [30]: %timeit np.isnan(data)[np.isnan(data) == False].size
1 loops, best of 3: 498 ms per loop
```

The double use of `np.isnan(data)` and the `==` operator might be a bit overkill and so I posted the answer only for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```
Counting the number of nans in each row:

import numpy as np

#create NumPy array
arr = np.array([[5, 6, 7, 7], [np.nan, np.nan, 14, 10], [np.nan, 11, 14, 15]])

#count number of values in array equal to NaN
arr3 = np.where(np.isnan(arr),1,0)
np.sum(arr3, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
len([i for i in data if np.isnan(i) == True])
```

Comment: Downvoted: the loop will be slower than any of the vectorized variants in the other answers and creating a list will take more memory (and I would argue harder to read). Also `if x == True` is very silly!