# Explanation needed: what does ~variable.MAKE.isnull() do?

Tags: python

```
data = input_data[~input_data.MAKE.isnull()]
```

I am new to python and have been learning the basics for a week. I am now working on certain data science projects using my basic skills. I have the above line in a Python tutorial that I'm going through and I'm not sure what it does. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context? Like a minimal working example?

Comment: Context would be great indeed. About the tild though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8305199/1524913

Comment: This is the tutorial you are talking about: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/s3.amazonaws.com/datarobotblog/notebooks/Getting%20Started%20with%20Data%20Science.ipynb What precisely do you find confusing about it? Which parts do you understand, and which do you not?

Answer (score 1):

The tilde `'~'` is the "bitwise complement" operator; per [the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> **`~ x`**
>
> Returns the complement of `x` - the number you get by switching each `1` for a `0` and each `0` for a `1`. This is the same as `-x - 1`.

`input_data.MAKE.isnull()` will give you the rows that contain nulls in `MAKE`, so the complement is the rows that do not, therefore:

```
data = input_data[~input_data.MAKE.isnull()]
```

will index the `input_data` by rows where `MAKE` **isn't** null, i.e. drop all of the rows where it *is* null.