# Not True, Python similar to R

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a Python solution similar to R's nice solution below?

```
# R
set.seed(1245)
array_truth <- sample(c(T, F), 10, replace = T)
array_int <- 1:10

# get the integers with False index 
> array_int[!array_truth] 

[1] 1 2 4
```

In R, you can use `!` to negate, but I haven't come across as nice a solution in Python:

```
# python
string_data = pd.Series(['aardvark', 'artichoke', np.nan, 'avocado'])
null_values = string_data.isnull()
null_values

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

The most Pythonic solution I know of is:

```
string_data[null_values != True]

0     aardvark
1    artichoke
3      avocado
dtype: object
```

If this is the best I can do, that's great, but I'm new to Python and haven't seen this specific question anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `~` instead of `!`:

```
>>> string_data[~string_data.isnull()]
0     aardvark  
1    artichoke
3      avocado
dtype: object
```

---

As @SethMMorton points out in comments, logical negation is usually done with `not` in plain Python e.g. `not True` returns `False`. `~` is the [bitwise NOT operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python). `pandas` overloads `~` to mean broadcasted logical `not` in these particular instances only, because Python doesn't allow overloading `not`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in general `not` is used in Python to indicate the logical opposite of a value, but in the specific case of numpy arrays or Pandas Dataframes/Series the `~` (complement) operator is used.

Comment: @SethMMorton This is true, and I have updated my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: @RyanErwin If this answer helped you and correctly addresses your question, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, will do. I think they make you wait 15 min

Comment: `~` isn't the "two's complement operator"; you probably misread the answer you linked, which talked about "two's-complement representation". `~` is the one's complement operator, or bitwise NOT. The closest thing to a "two's complement operator" is unary `-`, the arithmetic negation operator.