# Applications of '~' (tilde) operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation, tilde

I just discovered the [bitwise complement unary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) in Python via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) and have been trying to come up with an actual application for it, and if not, to determine if it's generally safe to overload the operator (by overriding the `__invert__` method) for other uses. The example given in the question fails with a `TypeError`, and the [link](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) provided seems pretty intimidating. Here's some fiddling around to see `~` in use:

```
from bitstring import BitArray

x = 7

print(~x)
# -8

print(BitArray(int=x, length=4).bin)
# '0111'

print(BitArray(int=~x, length=4).bin)
# '1000'

print(~~True, ~~False)
# 1 0

for i in range(-100, 100):
    assert i + ~i == -1
    assert i ^ ~i == -1
    assert bool(i) == ~~bool(i)
```

Are there *any* examples of valid use-cases for this operator that I should be aware of? And even if there are, is it generally acceptable to override this operator for types other than `int`?

Comment: In numpy/pandas, it is used for elementwise comparison of arrays. For example, if `arr = [True, False, True]`, `~arr` returns `[False, True, False]`.

Comment: @ayhan that's cool, so it applies a casting rule? Looks like it works for arrays of ints as well, but breaks down when combining `int`s and `bool`s: `~np.array([1, 0, -1, True, False]) -> array([-2, -1,  0, -2, -1])`. Could be used as a funky trick to convert `bool` values into `int` values though: `~~(np.array([True, False] + [1]))[:-1] -> array([1, 0])`

Comment: @Alec  Either you have an array of `bool`s or an array of `int`s. Mixing `bool`s and `int`s yields an `int` array.

Comment: It's also really useful for [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37553/31716)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard use cases for the bitwise NOT operator are bitwise operations, just like the bitwise AND `&`, the bitwise OR `|`, the bitwise XOR `^`, and bitwise shifting `<<` and `>>`. Although they are rarely used in higher level applications, there are still some times where you need to do bitwise manipulations, so that’s why they are there.

Of course, you may overwrite these for custom types, and in general you are not required to follow any specific semantics when doing so. Just choose what makes sense for your type and what still fits the operator in some way.

If the operation is obscure and better explained with a word or two, then you should use a standard method instead. But there are some situations, especially when working with number related types, that could have some mathematical-like operations which fit the bitwise operators, and as such are fine to use those.

Just like you would overwrite standard operators like `+` and `-` only for meaningful operations, you should try to do the same for bitwise operators.

---

The reason `~~True, ~~False` gives you `(1, 0)` is because the `bool` type does not define its own `__invert__` operation. However, `int` does; and `bool` is actually a subtype of `int`. So `bool` actually inherits the logic of all bitwise and arithmetical operators. That’s why `True + True == 2` etc.

Comment: That makes sense! So does `~` bear any resemblance to the `not` keyword? My initial investigations lead me to believe that `not` doesn't map to `~` and only really applies to boolean values.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. `not` is a boolean NOT operator while `~` is a bitwise NOT operator. Implementing the bitwise `~` will not impact the result from using the `not` keyword. `not x` in general is equivalent to `not bool(x)` which calls the special method `__bool__` instead (which has to return a bool btw.).

Answer (score 7):

> Are there any examples of valid use-cases for this operator that I should be aware of? And even if there are, is it generally acceptable to override this operator for types other than int?

Typically, you would not want to overload the `~` operator just because it is fun. It makes reading difficult. But sometimes, such overload for types other than `int` makes sense. [Take a look at how SQLAlchemy puts it to good use.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.notin_)

Comment: That's interesting, so SQLAlchemy uses it as a replacement for the `NOT IN` operation on columns?

Comment: It is a `NOT` operator, not a `NOT IN` operator.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't read the link carefully enough. Thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, it can be really neat when traversing lists.

```
for i in range(n):
    mylist[~i]
    #much prettier than mylist[-i-1]
```

Take a look at an example which rotates a matrix clockwise by 90 degrees:

```
def rotate( A):
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(n/2):
        for j in range(n-n/2):
            A[i][j], A[~j][i], A[~i][~j], A[j][~i] = \\
                     A[~j][i], A[~i][~j], A[j][~i], A[i][j]
```

(This snippet was taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-image/discuss/18884/))

Answer (score 3):

It's commonly used in [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) as a shortcut for a few things, such as using `~x` rather than `-x-1` or `~my_bool` rather than `not my_bool`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that operator in conjunction with the negation operator (`-`) to increment a number by 1. For example:

```
x = 5
assert -~x == 6
```

This is the only practical way I've ever used the `~` operator. Any other way it is used for anything apart from numbers, is generally context dependent and often add a level of complexity to understanding code.
For languages such as C++, Swift, Ruby, etc, you can overload this operator to mean anything which sometimes makes the code harder to digest quickly

Comment: `-~x` (or its friend `~-x`) has to be one of the least useful uses

Comment: @harold this is perhaps true, but I have never used any other variant that is more useful than what I have posted. Can you suggest any other?

Comment: And here I thought incrementing in-place was against the rules in python :) I actually think I've seen this in code golf examples before now that you mention it (not that the case for using it in readable code is improved by that observation!)

Comment: Typical/boring use is on bit vectors, such as flags

Comment: @harold wouldn't using it on a vector still require overriding `__invert__` since otherwise it'll fail with `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~`?

Comment: @Alec sure bit I just meant the typical "all integer types are bit vectors" type of bit vector

Comment: @harold oh I see, that makes more sense!

Comment: @Alec It doesn't increment in-place; it's just an expression equivalent to `1+x` (for some types; for example, it doesn't work for `float`s). The value of `x` itself is left unchanged.

Comment: @chepner *phew*, good to know that all is right with the world!

Answer (score 0):

Some methods such as the String find() will return -1 indicating 'not found'.  This is because character index 0 is a valid sub-string start position.  Because integers are stored as two's compliment the ~ operator can then neatly be used to discriminate between -1 and everything else.

For example:

```
test_sentence_1 = "There is a tilde in here"
test_sentence_2 = "There is not one in here"

if ~test_sentence_1.find('tilde'):
    print("1. Tilde Found")
else:
    print("1. Tilde NOT Found")

if ~test_sentence_2.find('tilde'):
    print("2. Tilde Found")
else:
    print("2. Tilde NOT Found")

1. Tilde Found
2. Tilde NOT Found
>>>
```

This works because signed integers are stored as two's compliment and if
you bit flip -1, which is what '~' does, then you get 0 ie False.
If you bit flip anything else but -1 you get a non-zero ie True

This use of tilde was common in C where many functions would return -1 to indicate failure

Answer (score 0):

**~x is equivalent to (-x) - 1.**

So it is handy to traverse an array or list in case we want to simultaneously operate on elements from both sides:

ie:

- (s[0] and s[len(s) - 1])
- (s[1] and s[len(s) - 2])
- ...

  ```
  def tilde(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
      print(nums[i], nums[~i])
  ```

For an input [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Output is :

```
1 9
2 8
3 7
4 6
5 5
6 4
7 3
8 2
9 1
```