# Python Pandas: drop rows of a timeserie based on time range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following timeserie:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2016-1-1')
end = pd.to_datetime('2016-1-15')
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='2h')
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': rng, 'values': np.random.randint(0,100,len(rng))})  
df = df.set_index(['timestamp'])
```

I would like to drop the rows that are between those 2 timestamps:

```
start_remove = pd.to_datetime('2016-1-4')
end_remove = pd.to_datetime('2016-1-8')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***using `query`***

```
df.query('index < @start_remove or index > @end_remove')
```

***using `loc`***

```
df.loc[(df.index < start_remove) | (df.index > end_remove)]
```

***using date slicing***

This includes the end points

```
pd.concat([df[:start_remove], df[end_remove:]])
```

And without the end points

```
pd.concat([df[:start_remove], df[end_remove:]]).drop([start_remove, end_remove])
```

Comment: Thank you that's good. Do you think there is a short syntax to do that with boolean indexing as well?

Comment: Outstanding, learning so much! actually query and loc are better since it is easier to decide whether to include or not start and end point. What does the pipe symbol stands for? (i could google it but its very difficult to get good answers on single symbol question)

Comment: `|` is the binary or operator that pandas hijacks to do element wise logical operations.

Comment: Ok so it basically is the same as `&` ? Or am i getting it wrong?

Comment: Yes, except it's "or" not "and".

Answer (score 6):

```
df = df.drop(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')), errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 4):

Another one to try.  Exclude the dates in the `date_range`:

Edit:  Added frequency to `date_range`.  This is now the same as original data.

```
dropThis = pd.date_range(start_remove,end_remove,freq='2h')
df[~df.index.isin(dropThis)]
```

We can see the rows are now dropped.

```
len(df)
169

len(df[~pd.to_datetime(df.index).isin(dropThis)])
120
```

Comment: Interesting; what does the symbol `~` stands for?

Comment: Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python

Comment: Please try again now.  I added a frequency string to the date range.

Answer (score 3):

An obscure method is to use [`slice_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.slice_indexer.html) on your index by passing your start and end range, this will return a `Slice` object which you can use to index into your original index and then negate the values using `isin`:

```
In [20]:
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.index[df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)])]

Out[20]:
                     values
timestamp                  
2016-01-01 00:00:00       0
2016-01-01 02:00:00      57
2016-01-01 04:00:00      98
2016-01-01 06:00:00      82
2016-01-01 08:00:00      24
2016-01-01 10:00:00       1
2016-01-01 12:00:00      41
2016-01-01 14:00:00      14
2016-01-01 16:00:00      40
2016-01-01 18:00:00      48
2016-01-01 20:00:00      77
2016-01-01 22:00:00      34
2016-01-02 00:00:00      88
2016-01-02 02:00:00      58
2016-01-02 04:00:00      72
2016-01-02 06:00:00      24
2016-01-02 08:00:00      32
2016-01-02 10:00:00      44
2016-01-02 12:00:00      57
2016-01-02 14:00:00      88
2016-01-02 16:00:00      97
2016-01-02 18:00:00      75
2016-01-02 20:00:00      46
2016-01-02 22:00:00      31
2016-01-03 00:00:00      60
2016-01-03 02:00:00      73
2016-01-03 04:00:00      79
2016-01-03 06:00:00      71
2016-01-03 08:00:00      53
2016-01-03 10:00:00      70
...                     ...
2016-01-12 14:00:00       5
2016-01-12 16:00:00      42
2016-01-12 18:00:00      17
2016-01-12 20:00:00      94
2016-01-12 22:00:00      63
2016-01-13 00:00:00      63
2016-01-13 02:00:00      50
2016-01-13 04:00:00      44
2016-01-13 06:00:00      35
2016-01-13 08:00:00      59
2016-01-13 10:00:00      53
2016-01-13 12:00:00      16
2016-01-13 14:00:00      68
2016-01-13 16:00:00      66
2016-01-13 18:00:00      56
2016-01-13 20:00:00      18
2016-01-13 22:00:00      59
2016-01-14 00:00:00       8
2016-01-14 02:00:00      60
2016-01-14 04:00:00      52
2016-01-14 06:00:00      87
2016-01-14 08:00:00      31
2016-01-14 10:00:00      91
2016-01-14 12:00:00      64
2016-01-14 14:00:00      53
2016-01-14 16:00:00      47
2016-01-14 18:00:00      87
2016-01-14 20:00:00      47
2016-01-14 22:00:00      27
2016-01-15 00:00:00      28

[120 rows x 1 columns]
```

Here you can see that 49 rows were removed from the original df

```
In [23]:
df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)

Out[23]:
slice(36, 85, None)

In [24]:
df.index.isin(df.index[df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)])

Out[24]:
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       ........
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and then invert the above using `~`

**Edit**
Actually you can achieve this without `isin`:

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(df.index[df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)])]
```

will also work.

**Timings**

Interestingly this is also the fastest method:

```
In [30]:
%timeit df.loc[df.index.difference(df.index[df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)])]

100 loops, best of 3: 4.05 ms per loop

In [31]:    
%timeit df.query('index < @start_remove or index > @end_remove')

10 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop

In [32]:    
%timeit df.loc[(df.index < start_remove) | (df.index > end_remove)]

100 loops, best of 3: 4.94 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jimbasquiat yes it uses `isin` but the difference here is that we don't generate any new index we query the existing index with the start and stop range which returns a `Slice` object which is just something we can use to index back so it would be more efficient than Adele's answer for large datasets but it's not terribly readable compared to PiRSquared's answer

Comment: Please note any solution by EdChum or @piRSquared is to be trusted more than my novice attempts :-)

Comment: @adele I think the main problem with creating a `date_range` is that it supposes that the index freq is consistent and that there are no missing values which would not be an issue for piRSquared or my answer but it works fine here, still +1 though