# Copy data from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to copy and paste data from a Jupyter notebook.  As per the following example which includes the `In` and `Out` elements.

When trying to copy this data I am currently unable to select the `In` and `Out` elements as these are not contained in the cell data.

```
In [23]:
df.index.slice_indexer(start_remove, end_remove)

Out[23]:
slice(36, 85, None)
```

This image shows the `In` and `Out` elements as well as the cells.  I want to copy and paste all of this.

[image]

Comment: Try saving as a python script - is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for looking @Phlya.  No, I just want to copy and pate as per the image I just added.  So when doing a copy and paste it would show the `In [149]:` ,  `In [150]:` and `Out [150]:` values as well as the cell data.  I'm pretty sure it can be done as I did it accidentally before but can't work out how...

Comment: I see. Saving as a script doesn't preserve the output, true.

Comment: @EdChum, is this something you did here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513324/python-pandas-drop-rows-of-a-timeserie-based-on-time-range/41514608?noredirect=1#comment70235633_41514608 as you have the `In` and `Out` data in your post.  cheers

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It helps when showing others how your code is written and what values are returned.  Please see the link in the comment above for examples. @Seanny123

Comment: @ade1e Want to know an ugly hack for it?

Comment: please show me @MYGz

Comment: If you start ipython in terminal, you can do it easily.

Comment: Maybe this is how others are getting the output.

Comment: I think this is to do with some loss of functionality that occurred between my version `3.1.0-cbccb68` and `4.0`, this stopped me from upgrading any further

Comment: @EdChum Check the better hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Less ugly hack:**

You can do this in console of Inspection Tool:

```
$('div.prompt').removeClass('prompt')
```

And you don't have to refresh the page. You can carry on your coding with the `prompt` class removed from all the `div` elements.   And you can select what you want at all times. But if you create new cells, you will have to run that again.

---

**Ugly hack:**

**Steps:**

1. **Right click** on `In [number]` in your browser and click on **Inspect Element**

You will see something like this:

```
`<div class="prompt input_prompt">In&nbsp;[18]:</div>`
```

2. **Double click** on class and **remove** the **`prompt` class** from the `div` element. After removing it, it will look like this:

   `<div class="input_prompt">In&nbsp;[18]:</div>`
3. **Press Enter** and **close** the inspection tool.
4. Now **click and select from left** of `I` in `In []` and drag your mouse inside the code block.
5. **Voila!** You got what you wanted.
6. You can **replace `prompt`** back or just **refresh the page**.

Comment: I appreciate you posting this as I learned something about the Inspect element functionality.  Added a +1

Comment: @ade1e Updated with a better solution. Check.