# How to search all data frame rows for values outside a defined range of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a data frame that's 50 columns and 400 rows consisting of all numbers.  I'm trying to display only the columns that have values that fall outside a pre-defined range (i.e. only show values that aren't between -1 to +3).

So far I have:

```
df[(df.T > 3).all()]
```

to display values greater than 2 then I can change the integer to the other number of interest but how I can write something to display numbers that fall outside a range (i.e. display all columns that have values outside the range of -1 to +3).

Comment: `df[~df.isin(range(-1,3))].dropna(axis=1)`. Avoid naming a column `T`, as `.T()` is a dataframe/series method.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `pd.DataFrame.mask`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-2, 4, (5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
print(df)

   a  b  c
0 -2  1  0
1  1  0  0
2  3  1  3
3  0  1 -2
4  0 -2 -2
```

Mask makes cells that evaluate to `True` `NaN`

```
df.mask(df.ge(3) | df.le(-1))

     a    b    c
0  NaN  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  0.0  1.0  NaN
4  0.0  NaN  NaN
```

Or the opposite

```
df.mask(df.lt(3) & df.gt(-1))

     a    b    c
0 -2.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  NaN -2.0
4  NaN -2.0 -2.0
```

Comment: @EdChum you already had my +1 because your answer was my first instinct

Answer (score 1):

You could call [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to stack all columns so that you can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas.Series.between) to generate the mask on a range and then invert the mask using `~` and then call [`dropna(axis=1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
In [193]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[193]:
          a         b         c
0  0.088639  0.275458  0.837952
1  1.395237 -0.582110  0.614160
2 -1.114384 -2.774358  2.119473
3  1.050008 -1.195167 -0.343875
4 -0.006156 -2.028601 -0.071448

In [198]:
df[~df.stack().between(0.1,1).unstack()].dropna(axis=1)

Out[198]:
          a
0  0.088639
1  1.395237
2 -1.114384
3  1.050008
4 -0.006156
```

So here only column 'a' has values not between 0.1 and 1

prior to the `dropna` you can see that the other columns don't meet this criteria so they generate `NaN`:

```
In [199]:
df[~df.stack().between(0.1,1).unstack()]

Out[199]:
          a         b         c
0  0.088639       NaN       NaN
1  1.395237 -0.582110       NaN
2 -1.114384 -2.774358  2.119473
3  1.050008 -1.195167 -0.343875
4 -0.006156 -2.028601 -0.071448
```

By default the left and right values are included, if this isn't required then pass `inclusive=False` to `between`

Comment: How do you get the `In [199]:` and `Out[199]:` elements as part of your output please? I asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520415/copy-data-from-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @ade1e OK I think I know the problem ever since some version of ipython, when copying and pasting it fails to select the in/out as part of the text selection, let me check my ipython/jupyter version

Comment: @ade1e I'm running ipython `3.1.0-cbccb68` basically I tried to upgrade to a newer version and noticed the newer version prevented this behaviour so I stopped upgrading