# Why does ~0b1 print out -2 in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, byte, ones-complement

I'm (somewhat) familiar with one's complement but I could use a refresher with regards to Python 2.7.

Why does `~0b1` print out to `-2`?

I understand that a one's complement converts 1s to 0s and vice versa. I expected `~0b1` to print `0b0` or `0`.

Does `print` automatically convert byte literals to some form of `int`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That isn't a *byte literal*. That is *another type of `int` literal that let's you express your `int` in binary*. So there is no conversion because *it was always an `int`*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the comment. That explains a bit.

Comment: So, in other words, `0b10000`, `0x10`, and `16` are all literals for the same `int` object. by default, when an `int` is printed to a screen, it's decimal representation is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0b1` is just another way of writing `0b0000...01` (integer 1). With `~` you'll get the bit-wise complement `1 -> 0` and `0 -> 1` (including the sign bit) so you get:

```
0b111....10
```

which is `-2`.

Comment: Your answer, combined with the top answer at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) really helped me understand what was happening.

Thank you!