# python pandas select rows where two columns are (not) equal

Tags: python, pandas

```
hsp.loc[hsp['Len_old'] == hsp['Len_new']]
```

I try this code, it's working.

But I tried these three

```
hsp.loc[hsp['Type_old'] == hsp['Type_new']] 
hsp.loc[hsp['Type_old'] != hsp['Type_new']] 
hsp.loc[hsp['Len_old'] != hsp['Len_new']]
```

They are not working.

My data table hsp is like

```
id  Type_old  Type_new  Len_old  Len_new
1    Num       Num       15       15
2    Num       Char      12       12
3    Char      Num       10       8
4    Num       Num       4        5
5    Char      Char      9        10
```

Is there a better approach to select rows where two columns are not queal.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Whats' the expected output? What's the actual output?

I ran the commands you mentioned and they are working I expect them to.

Comment: it is working on my side

Comment: Feel free to up-vote my answer as well if you found it useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ways to be confused by `==` versus `!=` when comparing `pd.Series`

**As expected**

```
df[['Len_old', 'Len_new']].assign(NE=df.Len_old != df.Len_new)

   Len_old  Len_new     NE
0       15       15  False
1       12       12  False
2       10        8   True
3        4        5   True
4        9       10   True
```

---

**But if one of the column's values were strings!**

```
df[['Len_old', 'Len_new']].assign(NE=df.Len_old.astype(str) != df.Len_new)

   Len_old  Len_new    NE
0       15       15  True
1       12       12  True
2       10        8  True
3        4        5  True
4        9       10  True
```

---

Make sure both are the same types.

Answer (score 42):

Use the [complement operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) `~`

```
hsp.loc[~(hsp['Type_old'] == hsp['Type_new'])]
```

which gives:

```
   id Type_old Type_new  Len_old  Len_new
1   2      Num     Char       12       12
2   3     Char      Num       10        8
```

When dealing with Boolean operations, the complement operator is a handy way to invert `True` with `False`

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45041174/2946517) said, had an issue with types.

Besides that, you could use comparing methods, in this case [pd.Series.ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)

Using your data:

```
hsp.loc[hsp['Type_old'].ne(hsp['Type_new'])]
```

But again, as piRSquared mentioned, because of dtypes it didn't work.
Just in case, you have to take care about `NaN`/`None` values at your data... such:

```
hsp.loc[ ( hsp['Type_old'].ne(hsp['Type_new']) ) && (hsp['Type_old'].notna())]
```

In this case, `.ne` has another argument, `fill_value`, which fill missing data.

---

In addition, you could use "compare" method to show difference between two series (or DataFrames)

```
hsp.Len_old.compare(hsp.Len_new)
```

And it might return (if columns were of the same dtype):

```
   self  other
2  10.0    8.0
3   4.0    5.0
4   9.0   10.0
```

But just force to have another dtype:

```
hsp.Len_old.compare(hsp.Len_new.astype('str')) # string type new column
```

It will return all rows:

```
   self other
0   15  15
1   12  12
2   10  8
3   4   5
4   9   10
```

Comment: Pandas Version: 1.2.2

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here:

```
In [7]: hsp.query('Type_old != Type_new')
Out[7]: 
   id Type_old Type_new  Len_old  Len_new
1   2      Num     Char       12       12
2   3     Char      Num       10        8
```