# Negation of an integer is giving unexpected result

Tags: java, binary

I am unable to understand how the following code gives -12. Please help me.

```
int a=11;    
int result=~a;    
System.out.println(result);
```

I thought it will give 4. but yes I saw a preceding zero.
I guess it has got something to do with 2's complement but cant makes out how.

Comment: 2's complement = (-x) - 1.
Thus, this would be giving you -12. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python

Answer (score 4):

`11`'s binary representation is `00000000000000000000000000001011`.

The negation of that number  is `11111111111111111111111111110100`.

That's the 2's complement representation of `-12`.

Comment: thank you Eran for quick response but how do i convert 0100 to -12 and how to know i have to do 2's complement?

Comment: @pankaj A negative number is always represented in Java as 2' complement. When you negate a positive number, you'll get a negative number. The value of `11111111111111111111111111110100` is -12 since you have to add 1100 (12) to it to reach 2^32 (1 followed by 32 0s). Similarly `11111111111111111111111111111111` is `-1`, since you have to add 1 to it to reach 2^32.