# what num[~ Wavy lines ] in python means?

Tags: python

I encountered a problem in leetcode named `246. Strobogrammatic Number`

```
class Solution(object):
    def isStrobogrammatic(self, num):
        return all(num[i] + num[~i] in '696 00 11 88' for i in range(len(num)/2+1))
```

i am curious of what `num[~i]` means?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The tilde operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

`~` is the `NOT` Bitwise operator. Essentially it will invert all the bits.

So if you performed `~` on 4 bits like `0101`, it would invert to `1010`.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746642/2178599) a helpful answer that I found, as Bitwise operators can turn into a complex topic that has surely been covered on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(10):
...  print(i, ~i)
...
0 -1
1 -2
2 -3
3 -4
4 -5
5 -6
6 -7
7 -8
8 -9
9 -10
```

It (probably) means reversing the binany representation of the number.