# Python Pandas Dataframe perpetual cumprod

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample of the Dataframe (population rows 100k+):

In:

```
    official        delta
    0               0.000201567           
    0               0.000194400            
    0               0.000151906            
    62.94957331     0.000144387            
    64.06471633     0.000125152            
    64.51335098     0.000133459            
    64.4101024      0.000120795            
    0               0.000146456
```

but receive the following output:

```
official        delta               result
0               0.000201567         0
0               0.0001944           0 
0               0.000151906         0
62.94957331     0.000144387         0
64.06471633     0.000125152         0
64.51335098     0.000133459         0
64.4101024      0.000120795         0
0               0.000146456         0
```

Desired solution:

```
official     delta          result
0            0.000201567    0
0            0.0001944      0
0            0.000151906    0
62.94957331  0.000144387    62.94957331
64.06471633  0.000125152    64.06471633
64.51335098  0.000133459    64.51335098
64.4101024   0.000120795    64.4101024
0            0.000146456    63.76600137
```

I tried the following code although it seems that it does not work correctly. I do not understand why it gives a fault result. When I execute it in a demo dataframe, everything is fine.

The code should pick up the 'official' element when mask is True otherwise multiply its previous element with 0.99 . The issue here is that when the mask is True, the code does not pick the 'official' element.

```
mask = (df['official']<51) & (df['delta']>0)

df['result'] = df['official'].where(mask,0.99).groupby(~mask.cumsum()).cumprod()
```

Comment: You're calling mask as a function the second time - `~mask()` - when it probably shouldn't be. Try `df['result'] = df['official'].where(mask,0.99).groupby(~mask).cumprod()`

Comment: sorry it was a typo, wrong copy paste. see now what my code is.

Comment: You say you want the code to use the official element when mask is True, but your mask will be False when official < 51, even though your desired output shows you want 62.94 to give a result of 62.94.   There's a sign error somewhere.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you. Index rows 0,1,2 mask is false; 3,4,5,6 mask is true; 7 mask is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = ~((df['official'] < 51) & (df['delta'] > 0))    
df['result1'] = df['official'].where(mask, 0.99*df['official'].shift(1)).fillna(0.0)
```

Add a [unary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) to `mask` with `~`. If the mask element is True, that element, otherwise, shift 'official' down by one row and multiply by 0.99. Fill the first element which will be `NaN` caused by the shift.

Result:

```
    official     delta     result    result1
0   0.000000  0.000202   0.000000   0.000000
1   0.000000  0.000194   0.000000   0.000000
2   0.000000  0.000152   0.000000   0.000000
3  62.949573  0.000144  62.949573  62.949573
4  64.064716  0.000125  64.064716  64.064716
5  64.513351  0.000133  64.513351  64.513351
6  64.410102  0.000121  64.410102  64.410102
7   0.000000  0.000146  63.766001  63.766001
```