# Splitting a dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my dataframe into two based of `medical_plan_id`. If it is empty, into `df1`. If not empty into `df2`.

```
df1 = df_with_medicalplanid[df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] == ""]
df2 = df_with_medicalplanid[df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] is not ""]
```

The code below works, but if there are no empty fields, my code raises `TypeError("invalid type comparison")`.

```
df1 = df_with_medicalplanid[df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] == ""]
```

How to handle such situation?

My df_with_medicalplanid looks like below:

```
wellthie_issuer_identifier       ...       medical_plan_id
0                   UHC99806       ...                  None
1                   UHC99806       ...                  None
```

Comment: change `is not` to `!=` ?

Comment: What dtype is in column `'medical_plan_id'`? If it is an integer or float, then comparing with "" will cause a type error. You could try using `.isnull()` instead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Use `==`, not `is`, to test equality

Likewise, use `!=` instead of `is not` for inequality.

`is` has a special meaning in Python. It returns `True` if two variables point to the same object, while `==` checks if the objects referred to by the variables are equal. See also [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).

#### Don't repeat mask calculations

The Boolean masks you are creating are the most expensive part of your logic. It's also logic you want to *avoid* repeating manually as your first and second masks are inverses of each other. You can therefore use the [bitwise inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) `~` ("tilde"), also accessible via [`operator.invert`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.inv), to negate an existing mask.

#### Empty strings are different to null values

Equality versus empty strings can be tested via `== ''`, but equality versus null values requires a specialized method: [`pd.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html). This is because null values are represented in NumPy arrays, which are used by Pandas, by `np.nan`, and `np.nan != np.nan` [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/9209546).

If you want to replace empty strings with null values, you can do so:

```
df['medical_plan_id'] = df['medical_plan_id'].replace('', np.nan)
```

Conceptually, it makes sense for missing values to be null (`np.nan`) rather than empty strings. But the opposite of the above process, i.e. converting null values to empty strings, is also possible:

```
df['medical_plan_id'] = df['medical_plan_id'].fillna('')
```

If the difference matters, you need to *know your data* and apply the appropriate logic.

#### Semi-final solution

Assuming you do indeed have null values, calculate a single Boolean mask and its inverse:

```
mask = df['medical_plan_id'].isnull()

df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]
```

#### Final solution: avoid extra variables

Creating additional variables is something, as a programmer, you should look to avoid. In this case, there's no need to create two new variables, you can use `GroupBy` with `dict` to give a dictionary of dataframes with `False` (`== 0`) and `True` (`== 1`) keys corresponding to your masks:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['medical_plan_id'].isnull())))
```

Then `dfs[0]` represents `df2` and `dfs[1]` represents `df1` (see also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947460/9209546)). A variant of the above, you can forego dictionary construction and use Pandas `GroupBy` methods:

```
dfs = df.groupby(df['medical_plan_id'].isnull())

dfs.get_group(0)  # equivalent to dfs[0] from dict solution
dfs.get_group(1)  # equivalent to dfs[1] from dict solution
```

#### Example

Putting all the above in action:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'medical_plan_id': [np.nan, '', 2134, 4325, 6543, '', np.nan],
                   'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

df['medical_plan_id'] = df['medical_plan_id'].replace('', np.nan)
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['medical_plan_id'].isnull())))

print(dfs[0], dfs[1], sep='\n'*2)

   medical_plan_id  values
2           2134.0       3
3           4325.0       4
4           6543.0       5

   medical_plan_id  values
0              NaN       1
1              NaN       2
5              NaN       6
6              NaN       7
```

Comment: I was using something like this to `fillna("")` .which I guess I shouldn't be using. Without this , None is coming wherever empty and the semi final solution is woking

Comment: @user1896796, In my opinion, it makes sense that null values are `np.nan`, not empty strings, so I prefer `df['medical_plan_id'] = df['medical_plan_id'].replace('', np.nan)`. So I wouldn't use `fillna('')`.

Comment: I tried printing this way `print ("In df1", dfs[0])`. I am getting     `print ("In df1", dfs[0]) KeyError: 0`

Comment: Apologies. updated the question with the dataframe. This is after I have removed fillna("") as per your comments.

Comment: @user1896796, So do the solutions I outlined still fail? If so, we still need a [mcve] which **demonstrates the problem**. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) if you need help with this.

Comment: @user1896796, Good to know, you know better if you want/need the extra variables.

Comment: Love the idea of using `groupby`. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

Another variant is to unpack `df.groupby`, which returns an iterator with tuples (first item being the element of groupby and the second being the dataframe).

Like this for instance:

```
cond = df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] == ''
(_, df1) , (_, df2) = df_with_medicalplanid.groupby(cond)
```

`_` is in Python used to mark variables that are not interested to keep. I have separated the code to two lines for readability.

---

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd 

df_with_medicalplanid = pd.DataFrame({
    'medical_plan_id': ['214212','','12251','12421',''],
    'value': 1
})

cond = df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] == ''
(_, df1) , (_, df2) = df_with_medicalplanid.groupby(cond)

print(df1)
```

Returns:

```
  medical_plan_id  value
0          214212      1
2           12251      1
3           12421      1
```

Comment: Added `cond` in right side bracket as per @Ecube Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

```
cond = df_with_medicalplanid['medical_plan_id'] == ''
(_, df1) , (_, df2) = df_with_medicalplanid.groupby(cond)
# Anton missed cond in right side bracket

print(df1)
```