# Pandas: Split a Dataframe into separate Dataframes based on certain Column's string values

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Haven't found any answers that I could apply to my problem so here it goes:

I have an initial dataframe of images that I would like to split into two, based on the description of that image, which is a string in the "Description" column.

My problem issue is that not all descriptions are equally written. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Some images are accelerated and others aren't. That's the criteria I want to use to split the dataset.

However even accelerated and non-accelerated image descriptions vary among them.

My strategy would be to rename every string that has "ACC" in it - this would cover all accelerated images - to "ACCELERATED IMAGE".

Then I could do:

```
df_Accl = df[df.Description == "ACCELERATED IMAGE"]
df_NonAccl = df[df.Description != "ACCELERATED IMAGE"]
```

How can I achieve this? This was just a strategy that I came up with, if there's any other more efficient way of doing this feel free to speak it.

Comment: Please try to avoid images and put some data that can be easily loaded next time..

Comment: Related: [Splitting a dataframe based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966811/splitting-a-dataframe-based-on-condition/52967219#52967219)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask - then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

For invert mask is use `~`, filter rows not contains `ACC`:

```
mask = df.Description.str.contains("ACC")
df_Accl = df[mask]
df_NonAccl = df[~mask]
```

Comment: This works (plus it's much more efficient than the strategy I was thinking)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` to find the rows that contain the substring `ACC`:

```
df['Description'].str.contains('ACC')
```