# Standard output is empty in python3

Tags: python-3.x

This is a program of finding a string is palindrome or not. But When I run this code I got error "standard output is error".

```
class Palindrome:
  @staticmethod
  def is_palindrome(word):
    flag = word;
    lengths = len(word);
    j=lengths;
    lengths = lengths/2;
    lengths = int(lengths);
    for i in lengths:
        if (word[i] == word[j]):
            count = count+1;
            j = j-1;
    if (count == lengths):
        r = "yes";
    else:
        r = "no";
    return r
word = input();
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word));
```

Comment: In your loop, 'for i in lengths' 
Lengths is an integer. I think you want to use range(lengths).
Just incase if you'd like a pythonic solution, you can just type
if(word == word[::-1) :
Then it is palindrome.

Comment: For `for i in lengths` you will be getting an error

Comment: why oh why are you creating a useless class with a single static method? Just use a function please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the code,

First of all, you are trying to iterate a `int` like `for i in lengths` which will throw you an error. You must be using it like `for i in range(lengths)`.

Also, you are trying to do `count = count+1` even before `count` is initialized, which will be throwing an error. To solve this you can initialize the variable `count` before the loop to `0`.

Another issue with the code is that, you are tying to compare `word[i]` and `word[j]` where `j` is `length` which is not possible because for a string of length `n`, index runs from `0` to `n-1`. Therefore you must be using `length-1` as `j`.

Also, there is no need for semicolon in Python.

Correcting all the things that I have mentioned above you can re-write the code like this

```
class Palindrome:
    @staticmethod
    def is_palindrome(word):
        flag = word
        lengths = len(word)
        j=lengths-1
        lengths = lengths/2
        lengths = int(lengths)
        count = 0
        for i in range(lengths):
            if (word[i] == word[j]):
                count = count+1
                j = j-1
        if (count == lengths):
            r = "yes"
        else:
            r = "no"
        return r
word = input()
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word))
```

If you can use `~` operator you can tidy up the code to a great extend. It can be done like this.

```
class Palindrome:
    @staticmethod
    def is_palindrome(word):
        if all(word[i] == word[~i] for i in range(len(word) // 2)):
            return "yes"
        else:
            return "no"

word = input()
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word)
```

If you want to know how the `~` operator works take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) post.

You can improve it further if you can use indexing to reverse the string. If you can reverse the string and then check with the original one.

```
class Palindrome:
    @staticmethod
    def is_palindrome(word):
        if word == word[::-1]:
            return "yes"
        else:
            return "no"

word = input()
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome(word)
```