# What is the python / numpy "~" operator

Tags: python, numpy

I see this operator from time to time in different contexts. Typically, it is used in front of a numpy variable

For example:

`~some_numpy_variable`

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python.

Comment: If called on a numpy array it calls [`numpy.invert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html), which computes "bit-wise inversion, or bit-wise NOT, element-wise."

Comment: @DeepSpace:  While all those duplicates explain what bit-wise inversion is, it doesn't really explain why it work on a numpy array (which is that `~` is implemented by an object's `__invert__()` method--helpfully implemented by numpy as applying bitwise inversion to each element.)

Comment: Thanks everybody. This is embarrassing to have so many duplicate questions. I tried searching and googling. Something about the ~ token just did not return any results