# Drop from datetime index dataframe rows based in year month day from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have one dataframe like the following:

```
                       A     
2014-06-02 09:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00   ...

2014-06-03 09:00:00   ...
2014-06-03 10:00:00   ...

2014-06-04 11:00:00   ...
2014-06-04 12:00:00   ...

2014-06-05 11:00:00   ...
2014-06-05 12:00:00   ...
```

And another like the following

```
                       A
2014-06-03 13:14:00   ...
2014-06-04 16:33:00   ...
```

I need one dataframe like the following :

```
                       A
2014-06-02 09:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00   ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00   ...
2014-06-05 11:00:00   ...
2014-06-05 12:00:00   ...
```

That is: Drop from the first dataframe every row having year-month-day in the second dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You could use `floor`, and `~`(invert symbol), and check to see if index of dfb `isin` dfa:

```
dfa[~dfa.index.floor('D').isin(dfb.index.floor('D'))]
```

Note both indexes need to be datetime dtypes.

Comment: I came up with solution almost the same as yours :) +1

Comment: For clarification, `dfa[~dfa.index.isin(dfb.index)]` would be enough to remove every row having the exact same data as the second dataframe, `floor('D')` takes the datetime object and "rounds it down" to a day value, so that different datetime entries having the same "year-month-day" will match. If your indexes are not datetime types, they can simply be converted with `dfa.set_index=pd.to_datetime(dfa.index)`.

`

Comment: What the invert symbol means?

Comment: ~ means NOT or invert True to False or False to True. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305291/6361531