# why does ~(True ^ False) return -2

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I tried the following command line in python

```
In[1]: ~(True ^ False)
```

and it returned :

```
Out[1]: -2
```

Could someone explain this to me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The tilde operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python)

Comment: (True ^ False) returned True (i.e. 1 in integer form). ~ operator is one's complement (for example : ~x => -(x+1)). So ~True or ~1 will be -(1+1) i.e. -2.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how python handles booleans:

`True` is represented as  1, (See `True==1`)

`False` is represented as 0. (See `False==0`)

Without syntactic sugar and abstractions:

```
x=~(1 ^ 0)
x=~1
x=-2
```

Comment: and why ~1 gives -2

Comment: It flips all bits. 1 is in binary `00000001`, if you apply bitwise not, it is changed to: `111111...(set bits)...111110`. Each set bit is unset and each unset bit is set now.

Comment: One way to view tilde operator is as `~x = (-1) - x`

Comment: But then if I replace with 2 numpy boolean arrays A and B of the same shape, ~(A ^ B) works well (i.e it returns an array of booleans). Why is it the case?

Comment: @aka, the discrepancy you mention between pure Python and numpy is discussed here: https://joergdietrich.github.io/python-numpy-bool-types.html