# Why "~False" is -1 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why "~False" is -1 in Python?

I was using a boolean variable in Python. When I try to do not of that, it returns -1. I want to understand why so? why a variable a changing its data-type duo to this operation.

Trying to add more details

```
b0 = False
print(type(b0))
b0 = ~b0
print(type(b0))

>>bool
>>int
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you're running?

Comment: @B.Hoffman What more than `~False` do you need?

Comment: Do you understand why ``~0`` is ``-1``?

Comment: I do understand ~0 is -1
but ~False should be True. right?

Comment: @SourodeepBasu Well at least it's true. The bigger problem is that `~True` is also true :-)

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python

Comment: Well False is equal to 0, so if you understand `~0`, that covers `~False`.

Comment: Without more context, all I can tell you is that `True` and `False` in Python are represented as `1` and `0` respectively.

`~` is the bitwise complement operator in python which essentially calculates `-x - 1`

so since False is equivalent to 0 the bitwise complement of `False` is `-1`

Comment: I agree that `~False` being `-1` is surprising. It *should* arguably be a TypeError…

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bool)) and the values for `True` & `False` are 0 & 1 resp.

Comment: @khelwood With that explanation, I'd also expect `str(False)` to be the same as `str(0)`.

Comment: @superb Subclasses can override the `__str__`/`__repr__` implementation…

Comment: @superbrain It would be if bool didn't have its own repr implementation. bool does not have its own ~ implementation. Should we interpret the question as "why doesn't bool have its own ~ implementation?"

Comment: @khelwood Just saying that "Equal inputs lead to equal outputs" (which is what that looked like) was lacking something.

Comment: How much clarification does this topic still need? You did notice the duplicate this is closed as? Is something still unclear now that we have explained that bool is a subclass of int?

Answer (score 1):

The tilde `~` is the bitwise 'not' operator, not the boolean 'not' operator. To do a not you probably want 'not False'.

The reason for it changing its data type is that it treats False as binary 0 and then flips it to -1.

Comment: I am aware of that, I am wondering why python do that, why it changes the bool to an Int.

Comment: @SourodeepBasu it is not *changing*, try running `isinstance(False, int)` and see what happens

Comment: @Sourodeep As noted ... because it’s a **bitwise not**, not a **logical not**.

Comment: The bool class is a subclass of int. The bitwise operator only works on ints thus False is treated as such. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool. False itself it still a bool which technically is still an int in Python

Comment: @Tomerikoo Arguably `~False` does change the class from `bool` to `int`. `bool` just happens to also be a valid `int`…

Comment: @deceze but what do you mean by *changes*? The class of the object doesn't magically change. It just inherits some methods from the parent `int` which in this case are not overriden

Comment: @Tomerikoo Well, `type(False) == bool`, `type(~False) == int`; that constitutes a class change for all appearances. (Sure, arguably an operation using any operators doesn't need to preserve the type of the operand, but you get the idea and why it looks to OP like a change of class.)

Comment: @deceze yeah ok now I get what you were trying to say. I was reading it as changing the source, rather than changing the return type...