# Why does ~False give -1 and ~True -2?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I always thought that ~ was equivalent to not in Python, but I had a bug that made me find out this. Could someone explain to me what that is?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The tilde operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python)

Comment: False and True are also numbers 0 and 1. `~` is *bitwise* negation.

Answer (score 2):

[From the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its integer argument. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`. It only applies to integral numbers.

As to why `~False` would be `-1`, it's because for historical reasons `False == 0` and `True == 1` (they're not identical but they are equal, and `bool` is a subclass of `int`). If you apply the formula above, you get `~False` => `-(False + 1)` => `-(0+1)` => `-1`, QED.