# Why is (x & 0) different from (x & ~1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is `x & 0` different from `x & ~1`?

Shouldn't `~1` and `0` be the same since `0` is the complement of `~1`?

```
x = 21
print(f"x = {bin(x)}")
print(f"x & 0 = {bin(x & 0)}")
print(f"x & ~1 = {bin(x & ~1)}")
```

results in

```
x = 0b10101
x & 0 = 0b0
x & ~1 = 0b10100
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(bin(~1))`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. not quite true in Python, since integers are arbitrary length you'd need an infinite number of leading `1`s.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's 1s complement; Python doesn't use that. `~x` is equal to `-(x+1)` [for an integer `x`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/32bd68c839adb7b42af12366ab0892303115d1d1/Objects/longobject.c#L4300-L4303).

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually I have missed the fact the question is for Python, so I guess my comment is inaccurate. I will remove it to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thanks jxh and EugeneSh, this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between `~`and `not` here,

`x & (not 1)` will be equal to `0`

as `not 1` is 0 but `~1` is `-0b10` which is `-2` for a 2-bit representation.

You can read more on `~` operator in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305291/7092628)

Comment: But in Python, bitwise NOT is used using this (~) symbol

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/

Comment: @AldrinSaurovSarker the bitwise note is ~ only, but bitwise not of 1 is not 0, not 1 is 0. as 1 is represented as 0b01 hence ~(0b01) is -0b10.

Answer (score 0):

`~` and `&` are bitwise operations, not logical operations. The *logical* expression "x and False" indeed yields False, as does "not True":

```
print x and False
print x and not True
```