# Negative sum for ~bool?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a boolean array with 1 True. The sum is 1, as expected:

```
b=np.array(([True,False],[False,False]))
b.sum()
```

The inverse of b, has 3 True and the sum is 3, as expected:

```
a=~b
a.sum()
```

But the sum of ~b is negative 2:

```
~b.sum()
```

I'm sure there is a reason. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: *"the sum of ~b is negative 2"* - no, the negation of the sum of b is negative 2, it matters where you apply the `~`, to `b` or to the sum. `~1` simply is `-2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305225/16343464

Comment: Operator precedence: `~b.sum()` -> `~(b.sum())` -> `~(1)` -> `-2`