# What does the expression "~" mean

Tags: python, expression

what does the expression "~" mean?

[image]

Comment: what is the context?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python/8305225#8305225

Comment: It is bitwise negation.

Comment: `~` is the bitwise NOT Operator, `|` is the Bitwise OR operator, and `&` is the bitwise AND Operator.

Comment: Code needs to be provided **as text**, not images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Another good link on the topic: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `~` isn't an expression, it's an *operator*.

Comment: @Tbaki no, `~` on a `list` will raise a TypeError

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wierd, it work for a list of boolean  to filter a pandas dataFrame

Comment: @Tbaki no, it absolutely did not. You are talking about a `numpy.ndarray` or a `pandas.Series`, definitely not a `list`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes you understood what i was refering to so it's okay

Comment: @Tbaki no, you should speak precisely. This is programming, precise language is important. `list` means something different from either of those, and it is important to understand those difference and not to use terminology inaccurately or ambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its
> integer argument. The bitwise inversion of x is defined as `-(x+1)`.
> It only applies to integral numbers or to custom objects that override
> the `__invert__()` special method.

Comment: You may want to use this reference instead https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations

Comment: yes, that's better