# When is the pandas ~ operator useful, and why is it necessary when != already exists?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I often see the `~` operator used in pandas statements by people offering help on stackoverflow, but I can't think of any time where I've needed to use it because `!=` just naturally comes to mind for me first. So I'm wondering why it exists.

For example, this statement:

`(df['col_A'] > 100) & ~(df['col_A'] == 120)`

... could just as easily be written as:

`(df['col_A'] > 100) & (df['col_A'] != 120)`

I imagine there must be situations where one must use `~`, but what are they?

Comment: For example, when you use `isin`, it is the natural way to implemente a "not in"

Comment: There's some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python), but the gist is that `~` is the unary complement operator, which is performing a mathematical operation, while the comparison `!=` is comparing the identities of the operands.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping things simple and easy to read is important, and that's a good reason to have equals `=` and not equals `!=`.

Being able to have a logical not `~` is important because it can be applied to many scenarios and clearly changes the equals to not equals in this case.  Sometimes applying boolean logic can add complications and may require a better understanding of demorgans laws https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Having more than one way to do this is okay since the two ways increase the flexibility and readiblity of the language.